# Can not make NSTableView work in Swift3

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3

I am having problems getting NSTableView to work with Swift 3 and XCode 8. I have an app with one table and one column in it and trying to add items from NSMutableArray. Here is my code :

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.objects.add("one")
        self.objects.add("two")
        self.objects.add("three")
        self.objects.add("four")

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return self.objects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
    {
        let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

        cellView.textField!.stringValue = self.objects.object(at: row) as! String

        return cellView
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

However this gives me an error:

```
*** Illegal NSTableView data source (<NSView: 0x610000120820>).  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row
```

It looks like boths methods are implemented so I have no idea  why I'm getting this error.
The dataSource and the delegate for the table view are both set to the man View.

Comment: did you set your tables data source as delegate as self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pbush25 recommended I had to set the delegate and datasource in the code. Also, I switched the TableView mode to 'cell based' and then the final code looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.objects.add("one")
        self.objects.add("two")
        self.objects.add("three")
        self.objects.add("four")

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return self.objects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
    {
        return self.objects.object(at: row)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your numberOfRows method signature is incorrect for the current macOS SDK.  It should be:
`func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int`